# hadoop single node jar not running

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have set up a `hadoop` single node in windows.

When I execute the command ./bin/hadoop jar Prefix.jar PrefixJob ip op

the job is stuck. There is no exception or anything. but it is just stuck.

How to get it to run?

Comment: Are you able to successfully run the `wordcount` example?  If not, what issues arise from that?

Comment: ./bin/hadoop jar hadoop-0.20.2-examples.jar wordcount ip op6

Comment: i tried this as well.The program was stuck the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to run the WordCount example is as below which I just tested [yesterday](http://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/hdinsight-hadoop-on-azure-demo-submit-mapreduce-job-process-result-from-pig-and-filter-final-results-in-hive/) (on HDInsight):

```
hadoop.cmd jar jar_file_name.jar class_name iput_file_or_folder_name output_folder_name

c:\apps\dist\hadoop-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\hadoop.cmd jar    \  
c:\apps\Jobs\templates\635000448534317551.hadoop-examples.jar wordcount \
/user/admin/DaVinci.txt /user/admin/outcount
```

What you can do is look at the Job Log to understand what is happening. First visit your cluster to Open Job Tracker and then search for the Job ID to check the information about the submitted job.

Comment: thanks for the reply! it was a configuration problem. when i corrected it, the problem was solved